# Mapping a collection to extract monthly surface calculations to a table

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm totally new using GEE and Javascript.
I'm trying to calculate a monthly based time series of a lagoon surface area. Besides, I want to export the results to a .csv or similar to compute some statistics outside GEE.

I think I'm on the right way, but I need some help to keep going.

So far, I can calculate the surface area for indivuald months whith this [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c58c39a342efa56a89a060e1e2f6f043):

```js
Map.centerObject(area, 9);
Map.addLayer(area)

var thr = 0.35 // trheshold for water and non-water pixels

var h20mask = function(image) { // Water mask
  var water = image.gt(thr)  // convert to 1 those pixels above 'trheshold'
  return water.updateMask(water.gt(0));// mask pixels of non-water
};

var addMNDWI_L8 = function(image) {
  var mndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B6']).rename('MNDWI');
  return image.addBands(mndwi);
};

var addMNDWI_L5 = function(image) {
  var mndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B2', 'B5']).rename('MNDWI');
  return image.addBands(mndwi);
};

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(area)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVER',10));

var l5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T2_TOA')
  .filterBounds(area)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVER',10));

var l8withMNDWI = l8.map(addMNDWI_L8);
var l5withMNDWI = l5.map(addMNDWI_L5);

// Surface area January 2018
var l8jan2018 = l8withMNDWI
  .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-02-01')
  .mean()  // Just in case there is more than one image per month
  .select('MNDWI')
  .clip(area)

var water_l8jan2018 = h20mask(l8jan2018)

var waterArea = water_l8jan2018.reduceRegion({
   reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
   geometry: area,
   scale: 30,
   maxPixels: 1e13
});

print('January 2018')
print(waterArea);
```

In the case of Landsat 8, which is available from 2013-04-11 to 2020-01-11. I know I should map a months series using somethink like this:

```js
var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(2013,04,01); // from 2013-04-01
var months = ee.List.sequence(0, 69); // to 2020-01-01
var startDates = months.map(function(d) {
  return start.advance(d, 'month');
});
```

But I don't know how to do it and neither how to build and export a table or matrix containing two columns, date and area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can hopefully get you started:

```
var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(2013,4,1); // from 2013-04-01
var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020,1,1); // to 2020-01-01

var months = end.difference(start, 'month')
var monthlyWater = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, months.subtract(1)).map(function (delta) {
    var startDate = start.advance(delta, 'month')
    var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'month')
    return water(startDate, endDate)
  })
).filterMetadata('empty', 'equals', 0)

var monthlyWaterArea = monthlyWater.map(calculateArea)

// Just as a reality check
var firstMonth = monthlyWater.first()
Map.addLayer(firstMonth, null, 'water')
print(
  monthlyWaterArea.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(3), ['area', 'start', 'end'])
    .get('list')
)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: monthlyWaterArea, 
  description: 'monthly_water_area',
  selectors: ['area', 'start', 'end']
})


function water(startDate, endDate) {
  /**  MNDWI  ***
  MNDWI = ( G - MIR ) / ( G + MIR )
  Green = 0.52 - 0.60 μm
  MIR = 1.55 - 1.75 μm
  Landsat 8: G=B3, MIR=B6
  Landsat 5: G=B2, MIR=B5
  **/

  // MNDWI threshold for water/non-water pixels
  var thr = 0.35

  // ** FUNCTIONS ** //
  var h20mask = function(image) { // Water mask
    var water = image.gt(thr)  // convert to 1 those pixels above 'trheshold'
    return water.updateMask(water.gt(0));// mask pixels of non-water
  };

  var toMNDWI = function(image) {
    return image.normalizedDifference(['G', 'MIR']).rename('MNDWI');
  };

  // ** Images and Collections ** //
  var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .select(['B3', 'B6'], ['G', 'MIR'])

  var l5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
    .select(['B2', 'B5'], ['G', 'MIR'])

  var water = l8.merge(l5)
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)    
    .filterBounds(area)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVER',10))
    .map(function (image) {
      return h20mask(
        toMNDWI(image)
      )
    })
    .max()
    .clip(area)

  return water
    .set('start', startDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd'))
    .set('end', endDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd'))
    .set('empty', water.bandNames().size().not())
}

function calculateArea(image) {
  var waterArea = ee.Image.pixelArea()
    .updateMask(image)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: area,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    }).get('area')

  return ee.Feature(area, {area: waterArea})
    .copyProperties(image)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a226cbfe86b8f5e4738820f117cf67b5

Comment: Thanks! it looks like it does solve the problem. Now I need some time to understand how does it works, I found GEE-Javascript very confusing!